# How to indicate to the user that an SmtpClient form is doing something (mainly IE)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am sending an email using a form using asp.net and C#.
The values of the form are retrieved using their ids and are sent using SmtpClient.send() and this is all working just fine.

What I want to know is how to indicate that something is actually happening once you click send so that the user doesn't get impatient or misunderstand etc.

The website will primarily be viewed through a page viewer in Microsoft Connect and so they won't see the loading icon on the tab.
In Chrome the pointer changes to show a spinning circle which is great, but using IE there's no indication at all.
I tried replacing the contents of the div that the form is in with a loading gif but it only happens after the email is sent(, or fails to send), and it persists so if they want to send a new email I'd have to replace the form contents again which just seems like a faff, which is why I'm asking what the possible ways to do this are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've got it sorted. Basically on the submit button I added `OnClientClick` and got it done through jQuery by adding the image tag to the form. Because the form is created every time the button is clicked (because the contents depend on which button is clicked), the image isn't there after the email is sent. This wasn't the case when adding the image tag in the code behind where it persisted after the email was sent.

To sum up:

```
<asp:button runat="server" text="Submit" onclick="code_behind_function" onclientclick="javascriptfunction()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd open a jQueryUI dialog with a jQueryUI [ProgressBar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) in an indeterminate state on form submission.  It will appear as soon as the browser sends the request; your response could then redirect to a confirmation page saying their email had been sent.  Or perhaps just close the dialog and show a message on the current page if you are doing an AJAX request to initiate the send on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new thread to send your email directly, no waiting.

Answer (score -1):

use SMTPClient.SendAsync to send the mail in the background. Create an event handler to capture when the callback from sending mail completes, then hide your spinner.

E.g.

```
// Code to show your spinning circle goes here
client.SendCompleted += new 
        SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
...


private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Code to hide your spinning circle goes here!
    }
```

Here's a working example using javascript to show the image, then hiding it in the code behind. Doesn't require sending async. (error handling ommitted)

sendmail.aspx page:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            From: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
            To: <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div id="spinner_div">
            <asp:Image ID="imgSpinner" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ajax-loader.gif"></asp:Image>
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('imgSpinner').style.display = ''; document.forms[0].submit();" value="Send Mail" />
    </form>
</body>
```

sendmail.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Sendmail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgSpinner.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            client.Send(new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(txtFrom.Text, txtTo.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using webforms or mvc?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I don't think you're updated answer would work very well.  It looks like there'd have to be multiple post backs.

Comment: Nope - only one postback.